# Length of the side of a regular pentagon is $a$ & length of diagonal is $b$. Value of $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{b^2}{a^2}=$?

Tags: geometry

Length of the side of a regular pentagon is $a$ & length of diagonal is $b$.
Value of $\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2}=$?

Answer (score 5):

The length of the diagonal of a pentagon with a side with length $a$ is $\phi a=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}a$ which satisfies the equation $\phi^2=\phi+1$ or $\phi-\frac{1}{\phi}=1$ so by squaring we get $\phi^2+\frac{1}{\phi^2}=3$. By defitintion of $b$ we have $\frac{b}{a}=\phi$ and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{\phi}$ so $\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2}=3$ 
You can check [here](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/goldenratio/pentagondiagonal.html) for more details about how $\phi$ is related to pentagons.